# Make http call into for loop Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives, angular-universal

How is the best way to make a call for each item in a for loop in Angular2

```
<div class="post" *ngFor="let post of posts">
  Title: {{post.title}}   
  Comments: {{getCommentsForPostID(post._id)}}
</div>
```

I don't think this is the way to do it so i need another solution.

Update:

```
getCommentsForPostID(post_id) {
  this.commonService.getMethod('posts/' + post_id + '/comments').then((data) => {
    return data.result
  }).catch((error) => {
   return null
  })
}
```

The code to load posts:

```
this.commonService.getMethod('posts').then((data) => {
  this.posts = data.result
}).catch((error) => {

})
```

Common service that i use for http requests:

```
getMethod(path) {
  return this.http.get(this.api + path, { headers: this._makeHeaders() 
  }).toPromise().then((response) => {
   return response.json();
  }).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: why aren't your comments loaded in the post object directly ?

Comment: Also, why do you think it is not the way to go ?

Comment: Is not the way because the app is only loading and not giving any response.

Comment: Then you should trigger the requests for the comments when your posts are loaded. It's quite simple, but you need to show (the minimal relevant part of) your component code, and the relevant service.

Comment: @bryan60 this is the code:       
this.commonService.getMethod('posts').then((data) => {
        this.posts = data.result
}).catch((error) => {

})

Comment: need to see the common service, this would be far easier if you stopped converting everything into promises

Comment: Yes, i updated the question with the code that i use in the common service

Answer (score 1):

Inside your component

```
myCall(param){ return http.get(someUrl + param).map(res=>res.json())}
```

In your html you can use async to resolve the request

```
  Comments: {{myCall(post._id) | async}}
```

example how i am doing it.

[image]

Comment: but best thing to do is to create another component names "comments" pass in the the observable or the request itself and let the component handle w/e you which is also good practice.

Comment: Probably is the better way, but i want to make it simple for now

Comment: Been there done that. The simple way is to do it right. Its few lines more code but it will work perfectly well. I have added a screenshot showing you what i do in my app.

Comment: @RayLuxembourg I think you mean `{{myCall(post._id) | async}}` (one `|`).

Comment: @Pac0 yes sorry.

Comment: At the end i did it like this example, passing data from component parent (Post) to child (Comment)